# Markovitz Portfolio Optimization- Why do we associate risk with $\Sigma$?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, finance

I'm trying to interpret Markovitz portfolio optimization problems.

The specific problem that I'm looking at is as follows:

minimize $x^T\Sigma x$

subject to $p^Tx\geq p_{\min}$

$x^T1=1$

$x\geq0$

I know that I can interpret this as minimizing the risk, $x^T\Sigma x$, of the portfolio, subject to the constraint that the return, $p^T x$, is greater than a minimum amount, $p_{\min}$. Additionally, no shorting is allowed, which corresponds to the constraint that $x\geq0$.

I don't understand the purpose of the remaining constraint; namely, that $x^T1=1$. I also don't understand why we write $p^T x$ rather than simply writing $p$.

Furthermore, why do we associated the risk of the portfolio with the covariance matrix $\Sigma$, and why do we write it as the quadratic form $x^T\Sigma x$, rather than simply writing $\Sigma$?

Comment: $x^T \Sigma x$ is the variance of the portfolio. A high variance means that the actual return can be far from the expected return.

Comment: Why do we write it as the quadratic form $x^T\Sigma x$ rather than simply writing $\Sigma$?

Comment: $\Sigma$ is a matrix- you need to formulate an optimization problem in which you minimize or maximize a scalar.

Comment: @blargen remember $x$ is some linear combination of the assets (usually normalized to $\|x\|_1=1$, this is equalivalent to the constraint $x^T1=1$ when $x$ is nonnegative), it turns out that the variance of a linear combination of random variables is equal to the quadratic form $x^T\Sigma x$.

Comment: @blargen your portfolio consists of the worth of your combined assets *in agregate*, ultimately you care about minimizing its *overall* risk, subject to some constraint on its *overall* expected performance.

Comment: Out of the constraints $p^Tx\geq p_{\min}$ and $x^T1=1$, one is redundant. You need one of them to exclude $x=0$, but there is no argument for both.

Comment: Consider asking at [Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/), example answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29154/a-good-resource-to-learn-about-the-intuition-and-optimization-models-behind-mark **or** [money.SE](https://money.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $x$ are a column vector of *weights* on each asset in the portfolio. The constrant $1^Tx=1$ means the elements of $x$ all add up to one, i.e. the weights add up to one like weights should.

$p$ is a column vector of returns on the assets. To get the porfolio return, we take the average return weighted by the portfolio weights. This is precisely what $p^T x$ is.

$\Sigma$ is the covariance matrix of the asset returns, i.e. it is $E(pp^T)- E(p)E(p^T).$ The variance of portfolio return is $$E((p^Tx)^2)-E(p^Tx)^2 = x^T(E(pp^T)-E(p)E(p^T))x = x^T\Sigma x.$$